# Django breaks on urls containing "logout"

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication

I'm working on a Django web-app which has user accounts, and so has login and logout functions.

What I would like to have is mywebsite.com/accounts/login/ be the login page. This is working as expected right now.

This issue is with logout- what I would like to have is mywebsite.com/accounts/logout/ logout the user and redirect them to the login page. This, however, doesn't appear to work.

Here is my url configuration in accounts/urls.py:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

With this configuration, login works fine. But when I go to mywebsite.com/accounts/logout/, I am just immediately sent back to the page I'm currently on.

However, if I change the logout url:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logMeOutPlease/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Then mywebsite.com/accounts/login works as intended and mywebsite.com/accounts/logMeOutPlease works as intended. Is there a reason the first configuration won't work?

If I however move the logout functionality to the top level (i.e just mywebsite.com/logout/), then it again works fine.

For reference, this is what is in the "top level" urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other urls that I can't show here
    url(r'^redirect/',  include('mywebsite.apps.redirect.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/',  include('mywebsite.apps.accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^$',       RedirectView.as_view(url='redirect/')),
    url(r'^admin/',  admin.site.urls),
]
```

I am using Django 2.0.6 and Python 3.5.2, and my laptop is on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: can you provide main `urls.py` & `accounts/urls.py` ? That will be helpful in debugging the code

Comment: i've added the main urls.py. I've shown you all of accounts/urls.py, minus some imports

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so from what I understand so far, that behavior is actually correct. Since, views logic was not provided in your question, I will assume that the views are currently not using any @login_required decorators and the logout view does what it says i.e. logout. So without seeing the views logic we assume there were no instructions about where to redirect to on successful logout and no decorator so opens the same page again.

So here's the advice.

In your settings.py file:-

Add:

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'url_you_want_to_redirect_to_on_logout'

This will enable redirecting to the specified url whenever a user logs out.

And if it helps, similarly we also do have a 
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'url_you_want_to_redirect_to_on_login'

Comment: I have LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL configured how I want. The issue is, if I want the logout url to be "mywebsite.com/accounts/logout/", going to that url does nothing (you stay on the page you're currently on). But if I set "mywebsite.com/accounts/SOMETIHNGELSE/" to be the logout url, then the logout works and redirects as intended.

Comment: Alright, than probably all seems good. Possibly a typo somewhere might be causing this situation.